# Display last two(few) values without replicating in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi  I am trying to display last two(few) values in my index page How to do that in rails?

Here is my _index.html.erb file (rendering in new)

```
    <table class="table table-hover">

    <% PriceLog.order(price_date: :desc).each_with_index do |price_dated,index| %>  // problem is here in looping
    <tr>
        <% @products.each do |product| %>
            <td>
                <%=  PriceLog.where({product_id: product.id, price_date: price_dated.price_date}).last.price_date.strftime('%d-%B-%Y')  %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%=  PriceLog.where({product_id: product.id, price_date: price_dated.price_date}).last.price %>
            </td>       
        <% end %>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

and in my controller

```
  def new
    @pricelog = PriceLog.new
    @products = Product.all
    @price = PriceLog.all
  end
```

> Updated

Here is the output I am getting like this I have three different products like Product1,Product2,Product3 and respected date and price for that

[image]

Here my values are duplicating 3 times(every time i hit submitting in form values it showing 3 times but storing once ) How should i stop duplicating and display only last few values

Any help must appreciated

Thanks

Comment: can you please add a screenshot of the list you are getting

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something along the lines `Model.last(2)`?

Answer (score 1):

You're running a loop within a loop. Your PriceLog.each_with_index loops over all your PriceLogs, and then within it your @products.each (which you have defined in the controller) loops over all your products. So each Product gets repeated once for every PriceLog.

Outside of that, you have a lot of logic in your view. It's generally frowned upon to call the model from there; that should happen either in the controller, a helper, or some custom presenter object.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller instead of

```
@products = Product.all
```

change it to

```
@products = Product.all.order("id DESC").limit(2)
```